# why data receiver maxByOrNull of class requires validation of not being null?

Tags: java, kotlin, validation, null, empty-list

I'm new to kotlin and I have a question.

Well, here is the code:

```
   data class People(val name: String?=null, val age: Int?=null )

   fun main(){
       
   val people = listOf(People("Alice"),People("John",32))
   val older = people.maxByOrNull{ it.age ?: 0 }
   
   // val resultadoFinal = maisVelho
   println("${older?.name}")
    
   println("${people[0].name}")
}
```

if in `println("${older?.name}")` you take out the `'?'`, you'll get this error:

`Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type People?`

What I understoon is this means that there is a possibility that what maxByOrNull returns might be null, so you have to validate it as not being null.
My question is: Is that correct?

Also, reading about the maxByOrNull in
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html

There is this part:

```
val emptyList = emptyList<Pair<String, Int>>()
val emptyMax = emptyList.maxByOrNull { it.second }
println(emptyMax) // null
```

this part `emptyList<Pair<String, Int>>()` is very strange for me. What is that? I know he is creating an empty list, but what is this language? Will I learn this further? this Pair thing, why he puts String and Int inside it? Isn't there a simpler way to create an empty list in kotlin?

Well, that is it. Thanks.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html - basically Kotlin enforces a system where you either explicitly say things *definitely won't be null* (and it'll crash if that isn't true), or they can be null and you're required to handle that wherever it might be an issue. It's useful and you'll get used to it! Functions called ``*OrNull*`` explicitly return null as a "fail" result, which allows you to easily provide a fallback value, or only run the next steps on an actual (non-null) result

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, correct what you think about `maxByOrNull`. If the list itself is empty, you do not get back any element.

the `emptyList` function is just a convenience function to create a (typed) empty list containing 0 elements of type `Pair<String,Int>` (see [Kotlin docs for emptyList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html)).

Instead of an empty list one could have used `val emptyList = null`, but forces you to check for null, before you execute `maxByOrNull`: `val emptyMax = emptyList?.maxByOrNull { it.second }`.